# Environmental Protection of arduino

Tags: arduino

How to protect an arduino from dust and moisture ?
I have already made an RPM datalogger using arduino and placed it in industry.I wanted to protect arduino from dust and moisture.I also want to know the life of arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for that you put it into a box. You can spray the electronics with a special varnish to protect against the moisture.

Comment: The special varnish is called [conformal coating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_coating).

Answer (score 0):

For a reasonably robust housing with fairly low effort, you could try using a Fernco PQC-104 4″ Qwik Cap rubber boot on a 4" PVC drain cap. Both are available for a few dollars from most hardware stores. Then use cable ties to affix your electronics to a knockout cap placed inside.

You can see a few photos of loggers built into these housings at:
http://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/diy-arduino-logger-build-instructions-part-3/